# proofs involving power sets and universal quantifiers

Tags: quantifiers

Im having trouble solving with a proof problem "A is not equal to the Null class then the intersection of class A is a set" and help on proofing this?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $$\bigcap A\subseteq\bigcup A$$